# Allow only one selection of multiple radio buttons with different names. Simple_form Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm working on a view and attempting to create a form where only one of multiple radio-buttons can be selected as true. The radio-buttons are each hooked up to individual booleans.

Relevent Model Code

```ruby
class ModelNameReason < ActiveRecord::Base
  MODEL_NAME_REASON_OPTIONS = {bool_one: 'Reason 1',
                                            bool_two: 'Test Reason',
                                            bool_three: 'Consumer Reason',
                                            bool_for: 'Time Contraint Reason',
                                            bool_five: 'Problem with Requirements',
                                            }
```

Relevant View code

```
 = f.fields_for :model_name_reason do |builder|
= render 'model_name_reason_fields', f: builder
```

Comment: Show the code you have so far. Specifically, show the model and the relevant parts of the view.

Comment: try `MODEL_NAME_REASON_OPTIONS = [ 'Reason 1', 'Reason 2', ...]`

Answer (score 0):

Simple HTML:

```
<form method="post">
        <fieldset>
                <legend>What is Your Favorite Pet?</legend>
                        <input type="radio" name="animal" value="Cat" />Cats<br />
                        <input type="radio" name="animal" value="Dog" />Dogs<br />
                        <input type="radio" name="animal" value="Bird" />Birds<br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit now" />
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

Use the same `name="foo"` attribute for all radio buttons that you want to "link" to the same variable.

Comment: This is very useful - even more useful would be the answer with rails helper methods.